# Capturing an X-frame-options deny error as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, github-api

i have a client side iframe of my own node web app. when i am in the iframe and try to login through github, i get the following error in my console from the web app side.

> Refused to display
>   'https://github.com/login?return_to=%2Flogin%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id…localhost%253A5000%252Fauth%252Fgithub%252Fcallback%26response_type%3Dcode'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

is there a way to capture this error as a string in my code? I want to be able to use console.log to print it.

Comment: If your question is about recording that error message, you might have better luck if you update your title to reflect that. If your question is about both that *and* why you're getting the error, you might want to break it into two questions, since they're distinct issues.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I updated it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since this is a security error, I'm not entirely sure how it behaves. It's conceivable that it's impossible to capture in code, for security reasons, but I'd be a little surprised. Have you tried adding `yourFrame.addEventListener('error', function(error) { /* do something with error */ })`? If that doesn't work, you might be out of luck, but it's *possible* that you could get some less-precise erorr information by adding the listener to `window` instead of `yourFrame`. If that still doesn't work, then I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: i think the error might fire on the framing page, not the iframe itself...

Comment: it says the error is on the iframe's src page

Comment: Damn. I think you might be out of luck.

Comment: ok what about just detecting that there is an error, not even capturing the error?